# Calculate difference of days between two dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ca489834a3ad8d93faf565682fb97350)**

```
CREATE TABLE PaL (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    event_date DATE,
    costs DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO PaL
(event_date, costs)
VALUES 

('2020-01-01', '500'),
('2020-02-05', '325'),
('2020-03-20', '200'),
('2020-04-15', '400'),
('2020-05-11', '900'),
('2020-06-18', '700'),
('2020-07-19', '900'),
('2020-08-10', '100'),
('2020-09-04', '300'),
('2020-10-17', '850'),
('2020-11-22', '470'),
('2020-12-31', '800');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
difference_in_days
366
331
287
261
235
197
166
144
1
```

---

I want to calcualte the difference in days from `'2021-01-01'` to the `event_date` in the table. 
So far I have tried the following ways:

```
SELECT 
DATE_PART('day', '2021-01-01' - pl.event_date) AS difference_in_days_01,
('2021-01-01' - pl.event_date) AS difference_in_days_02
FROM PaL pl;
```

However, I am getting the below errors:

```
ERROR:  function date_part(unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 2: DATE_PART('day', '2021-01-01' - pl.event_date) AS difference...
        ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How do I need to modify the query to get the expected results as in **[MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=24dbea693a005362f7da6db5b9bc60b6)**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code below does exactly what you are asking for

```
('2020-02-29' - pl.event_date) AS difference_in_days_02
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the `DATE_PART` segment of the `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [Ftisiot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7605762/ftisiot) is correct.

Additionally, I also added the difference in years and months to the query:

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c703d8fc168d4c269d30407a82edce90)**

```
SELECT 

('2021-01-01' - pl.event_date) AS difference_in_days,

((DATE_PART('year', '2020-01-01'::date) - DATE_PART('year', pl.event_date::date))*12+
(DATE_PART('month', '2020-01-01'::date) - DATE_PART('month', pl.event_date::date))) AS difference_in_months,

(DATE_PART('year', '2020-01-01'::date) - DATE_PART('year', pl.event_date::date)) AS difference_in_years

FROM PaL pl;
```

More details about the date-difference-functions in `postgresSQL` can be found [here](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff).